# How can I change this date and time format to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss using bash, this is from an apache log file

Tags: regex, bash, awk

```
49,10.96.25.156,1274x40x1,-,02/Nov/2017:21:14:31,http-nio-443-exec-20,"POST/rest/webResources/1.0/resourcesHTTP/1.1",503,40,0,"-","SilkPerformer17.0""-"
50,10.96.25.156,1274x41x1,-,02/Nov/2017:21:14:31,http-nio-443-exec-25,"POST/rest/webResources/1.0/resourcesHTTP/1.1",503,40,0,"-","SilkPerformer17.0""9myyx9"
```

This is how the log file looks, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It is possible to have the time displayed in another format by reconfiguring apache: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#accesslog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pure awk solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f

BEGIN {
  FS = OFS = ","

  # build our lookup of zero-padded month numbers
  split("Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec", marr, "|")
  for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    mhash[marr[i]] = sprintf("%02d", i)
  }
}

{
  # 1:dd 2:mmm 3:yyyy 4:hh 5:mi 6:ss
  split($5, dtarr, "[:/]")

  # replace the column with our reformatted date
  $5 = dtarr[3] "-" mhash[dtarr[2]] "-" dtarr[1] " " dtarr[4] ":" dtarr[5] ":" dtarr[6]

  # print the whole line
  print
}
```

To use it:

```
$ awk -f redate.awk access_log
49,10.96.25.156,1274x40x1,-,2017-11-02 21:14:31,http-nio-443-exec-20,"POST/rest/webResources/1.0/resourcesHTTP/1.1",503,40,0,"-","SilkPerformer17.0""-"
```

Or you can make it executable:

```
$ chmod +x redate.awk
```

And run it directly:

```
$ ./redate.awk access_log
49,10.96.25.156,1274x40x1,-,2017-11-02 21:14:31,http-nio-443-exec-20,"POST/rest/webResources/1.0/resourcesHTTP/1.1",503,40,0,"-","SilkPerformer17.0""-"
```

Comment: Nice solution! Maybe more concise if you use a single array `split($5, tarr, "[/:]")` ?

Comment: @etopylight Ooh, nice! Updated!

Comment: Hey, sorry but I am very new to bash so I am not sure how to print it into a new file instead of displaying it on my console?

Comment: You just have to write it out to a file with the `>` shell operator: `awk -f redate.awk access_log > new_access_log`

Comment: @mwp I have a log parser already would you be able to help me integrate this redate.awk within that parser?

Comment: I can certainly try, but me not knowing anything about your log parser and you being new to bash might hamper the effort a bit. ;) It might be worth opening a new question, referencing this question, with more details about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @mwp Thanks! and will open another question!

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `date` or `awk` to do the conversion. 
If you have the `dateutils` package installed, here is a straightforward command that you can use

```
dateutils.dconv -S -i "%d/%b/%Y:" -f "%F " < file.log
```

- `-i` to specify input date format
- `-f` to specify output date format
- `-S` sed mode, to process only the matched date string

Input

```
49,10.96.25.156,1274x40x1,-,02/Nov/2017:21:14:31,http-nio-443-exec-20
```

Output

```
49,10.96.25.156,1274x40x1,-,2017-11-02 21:14:31,http-nio-443-exec-20
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am running bash on windows so I don't have the dateutils package :/

Comment: @ManishJha If you are using Windows Subsystem for Linux, since it is based on Ubuntu, you can simply use `sudo apt-get install dateutils` to install it

Comment: Unfortuantely I am running a  windows 7 and I have downloaded a bash-port for windows which doesn't have the dateutils package

Answer (score 0):

bash only conversion:

```
declare -A m
m=([Jan]=01 [Feb]=02 [Mar]=03 [Apr]=04 [May]=05 [Jun]=06 [Jul]=07 [Aug]=08 [Set]=09 [Oct]=10 [Nov]=11 [Dec]=12)
IFS='/:' read -r -a a <<< '02/Nov/2017:21:14:31'
echo "${a[2]}-${m[${a[1]}]}-${a[0]} ${a[3]}:${a[4]}:${a[5]}"
```

## EDIT

I mean something like this to read the file and split the lines

```
printline() {
    local l=("$@")
    echo -n "${l[0]}"
    for f in "${l[@]:1}"
    do
        echo -n ",$f"
    done
    echo
}

declare -A m
m=([Jan]=01 [Feb]=02 [Mar]=03 [Apr]=04 [May]=05 [Jun]=06 [Jul]=07 [Aug]=08 [Set]=09 [Oct]=10 [Nov]=11 [Dec]=12)
while read line
do
    IFS=',' read -r -a l <<< "$line"
    IFS='/:' read -r -a a <<< ${l[4]}
    l[4]="${a[2]}-${m[${a[1]}]}-${a[0]} ${a[3]}:${a[4]}:${a[5]}"
    printline "${l[@]}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am not sure how this would change the date format throughout the file that I have. I am new to bash so I am not sure how to implement it so it'll change all the dates throughout the file.

Comment: You have to split the lines, perhaps using the same split into array technique, then convert the date field, and print the whole line again

Answer (score 0):

using date for converting could be like this

```
IFS=,
while read a b c d dat remaining
do
    dat=${dat//\// }  # remove all / from date-field
    dat=${dat/:/ }    # remove first : from date-field
    echo "$a,$b,$c,$d,$(date --date="$dat" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),$remaining"
done < redate.dat
```

First we have change the date-field, into something date is able to understand.
Then we choose the output format as needed.

Comment: it gives me a bad substitution error when I try to run it.

Comment: Works fine for me in bash and ksh.  What shell version ? Mine is ksh: 93t+ 2010-06-21 , GNU bash, version 3.2.51.  Different input? What is the exact error message?